# DDE/IPC in linux gui?

Tags: linux, ipc, gnome, x11

There used to be Dynamic Data Exchange API (type of IPC) in windows which allowed sending notifications with params to running process and they would grab focus and conduct the operation. Is there anything similar in xwindows/gnome?

Like for example, when I get my phpunit errors, it comes with file path and line number. Was wondering if using any bash script or perl etc, I could grab the output and make the line below clickable

```
protected/tests/controllers/CmsControllerTest.php:17
```

so it quickly focus on my eclipse, open the file and moves cursor to the right line number.
phpunit and eclipse is just for examples. enough said.

Comment: Whoa. DDE. Last time I used that was >10 years ago. And it was antiquated even then

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to address this, would be to make the functionality an eclipse plugin.

There are lots of examples on how to write such plugins.

Moreover, you can probably lean on/reuse rather feature complete existing views (Problems view, Tasks view etc.) so making it look beautiful and matching eclipse should be a breeze.

Alternatively, there is a rich API that you could use to implement your own IPC channel to talk with your test runner outside Eclipse. An example of that is `eclimd`, the Vim-eclipse integration thing. Specifically, look at it's behaviour in ['Headed Eclipse'](http://eclim.org/eclimd.html#headed-eclipse-server) mode.